# How do I implement a distributed queuing service the likes of Amazon SQS?

Tags: architecture, queue, amazon-sqs

This question is at an architecture level. Assuming solutions like AWS SQS, Rabit MQ, Kaafka, etc are not an option.

How would go ahead and architect a queuing service which has the following points

- Basic queue requirement (Publish and consume messages)
- Distributed (scalable)
- FIFO
- Long Polling to the queue that will respond immediately when a new message is published to the queue
- Any DB can be used (SQL or NoSQL)

Comment: Are you asking how you could build your own solution? That's probably off-topic for StackOverflow unless you have a specific question. And why are existing solutions not an option?

Comment: Where do I ask for help in that case? 
The solution would be for a bank, hence cannot expose data to AWS. More importantly, it should be a bundled lightweight solution for low power devices.

Comment: Many banks are using AWS for their services, so that is not a valid blanket statement, but it will vary by organisation. In that case, why can't they use products like Rabbit MQ, which runs within an organisation's existing infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to build messaging services without using messaging software.  The answer is to build your own messaging software from the ground-up.  That's silly, you should not do so, you are likely not qualified.  Queues need skills in highly concurrent development techniques, and design and development of them is difficult to say the least.

Buy some messaging software, use some open-source software, or use a saas solution.  Don't roll your own.

More importantly, why are you trying to run a queue on an embedded device?  This is usually something that runs on a server.  RabbitMQ is not a large installation, anything with more than a gig or so of RAM can likely run it.  You likely could get it running on a Raspberry PI 3 with a little tweaking, but you wouldn't have room for much more than that.